# PInvokeStackImbalance when calling Delphi function from C# application

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I am forced to work with unmanaged delphi dll. I dont have an access to the source code. Only vague documentation:

```
type
  TServiceData = packed record 
    DBAlias: PChar; 
    LicKey: PChar; 
    Pass: PChar; 
  end; 
  PServiceData = ^TServiceData; 

function CreateRole(SrvData: PServiceData; var UserName: PChar): byte; stdcall;
```

`UserName` is supposed to be an `out` param.

My C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct SERVICE_DATA
{
    public string DBALias;
    public string LicKey;
    public string Pass;
}

[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern byte CreateRole(SERVICE_DATA data, out string str);
```

I have no idea what can cause the stack imbalance (except calling convention which seems to be correct). I dont know if strings in my structure are marshalled correctly but according to other threads this would not cause PStackImbalanceException. Any help will be much appreciated:)

EDIT.
I have implemented suggestions from David and now I am getting access violation exception:

"Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt”

My structure and method declaration is just copy-pasted from the answer, there is nothing fancy in the way I am calling it:

```cs
        string str;
        var data = new SERVICE_DATA();
        data.DBALias = "test";
        data.LicKey = "test";
        data.Pass = "test";
        var result = CreateRole(ref data, out str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the translation:

1. The Delphi code receives a pointer to the record. The C# code passes it by value. This is the reason for the stack imbalance warning.
2. The user name parameter is probably incorrectly handled on the Delphi side. It would need to be a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, allocated on the COM heap by a call to `CoTaskMemAlloc`. I'd guess that you aren't doing that and so you'll hit problems when the marshaller attempts to deallocate the pointer with a call to `CoTaskMemFree`.

I'd probably use the COM string type for the strings. I would also avoid packing records because that is bad practise as a general rule.

I'd write it like this:

**Delphi**

```pascal
type
  TServiceData = record
    DBAlias: WideString;
    LicKey: WideString;
    Pass: WideString;
  end;

function CreateRole(const SrvData: TServiceData; out UserName: WideString): Byte; 
  stdcall;
```

**C#**

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SERVICE_DATA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string DBALias;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string LicKey;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Pass;
}

[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern byte CreateRole(
    [In] ref SERVICE_DATA data, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string str
);
```

---

Here is a complete test project to show that this works as expected:

**Delphi**

```pascal
library Project1;

type
  TServiceData = record
    DBAlias: WideString;
    LicKey: WideString;
    Pass: WideString;
  end;

function CreateRole(const SrvData: TServiceData; out UserName: WideString): Byte;
  stdcall;
begin
  UserName := SrvData.DBAlias + SrvData.LicKey + SrvData.Pass;
  Result := Length(UserName);
end;

exports
  CreateRole;

begin
end.
```

**C#**

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string dllname = @"...";

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SERVICE_DATA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string DBALias;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string LicKey;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string Pass;
        }

        [DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern byte CreateRole(
            [In] ref SERVICE_DATA data,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string str
        ); 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SERVICE_DATA data;
            data.DBALias = "DBALias";
            data.LicKey = "LicKey";
            data.Pass = "Pass";
            string str;
            var result = CreateRole(ref data, out str);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
17
DBALiasLicKeyPass
```

Comment: After aplying your changes the pinvokestackimbalance exception is gone, but now I am getting AccessViolationException.

Comment: Perhaps you have a bug in your code. I cannot see your code. You asked about the stack imbalance.

Comment: You are right, this is not what I asked at the beginning, so I will mark your post as answer. Still - I have added some additional code to my question.

Comment: It must be something at your end. See my latest update.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. My code looks just like yours but I noticed you used record instead of packed record. Can this make a difference? Apologies if my questions are naive or stupid. This is my first encounter with delphi.

Comment: Packed won't make a difference here because all members have the same size/alignment and so there is no padding. I guess your code is not identical to mine. Try running mine.

Comment: Trust me, I tried. Since you seem sure about your solution, I am starting to suspect there is something wrong with the library itself. Thanks again for your help.